# How to find modules in subfolder webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there a way to set up webpack to find modules in subfolders like `./components/*/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [the config option `resolve.modulesDirectories`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories):

> An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory as well as its ancestors, and searched for modules. This functions similarly to how node finds “node_modules” directories. For example, if the value is `["mydir"]`, webpack will look in “./mydir”, “../mydir”, “../../mydir”, etc.